# SSMS Bulk inserts = Error + Which line is it?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to insert a lot of data with **SQL Server Management Studio**. This is what I do:

1. I open my file containing a lot of SQL inserts: `data.sql`
2. I execute it (`F5`)
3. I get a lot of these:

   ```
   (1 row(s) affected)
   ```

   and some of these:

   ```
   Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 26
   String or binary data would be truncated.
   The statement has been terminated.
   ```

**Question:** How to get the error line number ? Line 26 doesn't seems to be the correct error line number...

Comment: In the error section, check the 1st tab and it shows that

Comment: Search at line 26 for a field that is not big enough for your insert..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that has annoyed SQL Server developers for years. Finally, with [SQL Server 2017 CU12 w/ trace flag 460](https://sqlserverupdates.com/news/announcing-sql-server-2017-cu12-omg-they-finally-fixed-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/) they give you a better error message, like:

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 6, Procedure ProcedureName, Line Linenumber
>   String or binary data would be truncated in table ‘%.*ls’, column
>   ‘%.*ls’. Truncated value: ‘%.*ls

A method to get around this now is to add a `print` statement after each insert. Then, when you see your `rows affected` print out, you could see what ever you print.

```
...
insert into table1
select...

print 'table1 insert complete'

insert into table2
select...

print 'table2 insert complete'
```

This isn't going to tell you what column, but would narrow it down to the correct insert. You can also add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your script if you don't want the rows affected message printed out.

Another addition, if you really are using [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and weren't just using the term generally, you can specify an `ERRORFILE`. This will log the row(s) which caused the error(s) in your `BULK INSERT` command. It's important to know that by default, `BULK INSERT` will complete if there are 10 errors or less. You can override this by specifying the `MAXERRORS` in your `BULK INSERT` command.